# Ruby on Rails Active Record Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, activerecord

I'm developing a RoR application. After updating to Ruby 2.x and Rails 4.x, I get an CookieOverflowError. To solve this, I tried using an Active Record Session to store the session. I set it up with following commands:

```
rails generate active_record:session_migration production
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

And altered my configuration in config/initializers/session_store.rb
    AppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store

This comes up in the log/production.log file:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-5.0.0/lib/arel/crud.rb:5:in `compile_update'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:500:in `update_record'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:70:in `update_record'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:74:in `update_record'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `block in update_record'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4115952957871857265__update__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `update_record'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `update_record'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:478:in `create_or_update'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:393:in `_run__4115952957871857265__save__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-55dc59aff9a1/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:80:in `block in set_session'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in quietly'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:50:in `silence_stream'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:109:in `block in quietly'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:50:in `silence_stream'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:108:in `quietly'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-55dc59aff9a1/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:77:in `set_session'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:342:in `commit_session'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `context'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2968889427859779895__call__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

I created a separate log file which prints the contents of record, on which the method save is called. It's that save method that fails (active_record_store.rb).

```
D, [2014-04-04T11:18:09.058984 #31574] DEBUG -- : #<ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session id: 1, session_id: "11f19fdf6d404a4667f11458bedf157f", data: "BAh7BkkiEGluaXRpYWxfdXJpBjoGRVRJIi1odHRwczovL2ljb3N...", created_at: "2014-04-04 08:47:18", updated_at: "2014-04-04 08:47:18">
```

From the rails console:

```
2.1.1 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
 => ["schema_migrations", "items", "roles", "rights", "roles_users", "rights_roles", "users", "queue_messages", "mammie_tokens", "sessions"]
2.1.1 :002 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns('sessions')
 => [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Column:0x00000002a80078 @name="id", @sql_type="INTEGER", @null=false, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:integer, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>, #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Column:0x00000002a62a00 @name="session_id", @sql_type="varchar(255)", @null=false, @limit=255, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:string, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>, #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Column:0x00000002a60c00 @name="data", @sql_type="text", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:text, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>, #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Column:0x00000002a60840 @name="created_at", @sql_type="datetime", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>, #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Column:0x00000002a602c8 @name="updated_at", @sql_type="datetime", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>]
```

Active Record's own log files:

```
# Logfile created on 2014-04-04 13:13:35 +0200 by logger.rb/44203
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.163858 #11512] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."session_id" = '871b57e38039360f4aeaa61857e90605' ORDER BY "sessions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.176779 #11512] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (UPPER(username) = 'ADMINISTRATOR' and hashed_pasword = 'HASH') ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.216335 #11512] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.241415 #11512] DEBUG -- :   SQL (20.6ms)  INSERT INTO "mammie_tokens" ("created_at", "token", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 04 Apr 2014 11:13:37 UTC +00:00], ["token", "token_17a75000-9518-0131-0160-2565bbb3839e"], ["updated_at", Fri, 04 Apr 2014 11:13:37 UTC +00:00]]
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.252799 #11512] DEBUG -- :    (10.8ms)  commit transaction
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.264598 #11512] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
D, [2014-04-04T13:13:37.272679 #11512] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
```

However, I keep getting the same error over and over again, as something goes wrong when (I guess) something is being saved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What should I include in my post as well? My guess is that ActiveRecord itself does not work properly, is there any way to test this?

Comment: ActiveRecord has been tested and tried well. You can run the test to check it. You can run test cases Do look for some problem with the way you are using it. Mostly the errors we encounter might be in a misunderstanding of the gem. Also being open-sourced if you hit a limitation you can always change it to suit your own needs.

Comment: I created a separate log file which prints the contents of record, on which the method save is called. It's that save method that fails (active_record_store.rb). #<ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session id: 1, session_id: "11f19fdf6d404a4667f11458bedf157f", data: "BAh7BkkiEGluaXRpYWxfdXJpBjoGRVRJIi1odHRwczovL2ljb3N...", created_at: "2014-04-04 08:47:18", updated_at: "2014-04-04 08:47:18">
In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with this record in terms of arguments whatsoever, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check, that you are not storing any big data files in session and any data whose size is greater than the size of "data" db column.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid there is something else going wrong here. I replaced the `record.data = session_data` line with `record.data = ''`, and the problem still persists. Also, Rails is raising an ArgumentError exception.

Comment: I'd interested to see the line where you are putting values in "session" variable

Comment: `def signin ... session['user'] = user ... session['token'] = token ... end`

Comment: and post your user model

Comment: I've added the user model to the original question for better readability

Comment: What is this mammie_tokens? how are you saving it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to GEM incompatibility. I recently updated the active_records and arel GEMS, which are known to be prone to compatibility issues. On this line:

```
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-5.0.0/lib/arel/crud.rb:5:in `compile_update'
```

the function compile_update expects two parameters, but apparently only gets one, because of the use of incompatible versions of active_records and adel.